# how to check whether apache user has write privileges on a directory using php. (for linux and windows)

Tags: php

how to check whether apache user has write privileges on a directory using php for both OS (linux and windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [is_writable()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) on the directory.

You have to put this in a web page served by apache and call it from your browser to have it run as the same user as apache. It won't work if you call it in your terminal.

Comment: are you sure is_writable checks for apache user?

Comment: It will operate as the user running the script, which if you are using mod_php, will be the user that Apache is running as.

Comment: @tecman: yes, but as noted on the documentation, it doesn't handle safe mode (that is DEPRECATED since PHP 5.3.0).

Comment: tecman: Use is_writable() on the directory, and forget about safe mode. (It's broken anyway). If you *REALLY* need to handle the safe mode case, just try to create a dummy file with a random filename.

Comment: tecman: oh... i edited the answer to reply to that (about the terminal)

Comment: thanks a lot steve, one last question related to it, in case if the permissions of the directory are 770, do i need to make apache user a member of the group in order to have it the write permissions???

Comment: tecman: it actually depends on the users and groups involved. With 770, you're right, either the *user* or the *group* of apache has to match the owner of the directory.

Comment: tecman: btw, if you are ok with an answer, just click on the "accept" tick mark. (it says thank you, and even give you +2 reputation)